# Передать переменную из Javascript в Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Всем привет. Работаю над проектом(Фронт js, бэк - Django)
На стороне клиента получаю массив, содержащий определенные айди. Вопрос, как можно передать этот массив из JavaScript'а в Django, чтобы в Django я мог продолжить работу с ним.
в js имею массив `repl = [1, 4, 6, 44, 77, 98, ..., n];`
хочу получить на стороне джанго переменную, содержащую эти же значения.
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: кажется то что вы ищете как раз тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208067/wheres-my-json-data-in-my-incoming-django-request

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно